# Help with a Kazakh postal address

Tags: орфография, транслитерация

I want to send a card to a friend in Kazakhstan. The address as she once gave me is:

> Kostanai city, Abaya 9/1, 1 "B"

and I believe the postal code is 110005 (but may be wrong).

From my looking around online I think the address should be...

> Abaya 9/1, 1 "B"
>     Костанай, Костанайский ОФ
>     Костанайская область
>     Kazakhstan (KZ)
>     110005

Is this correct? What is "Abaya" in Cyrillic writing?

Comment: Abaya must be Абая. And don't forget to change Latin "B" to Cyrillic "Б".

Comment: Additionally, Abay was a Kazakh poet. "Abaya" is a street name in his honor. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abai_Qunanbaiuli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually "Abaya" is written in Latin and it is correct. 
I think it should be like this:

**110005 Abaya street 9/1, 1 "B",
Kostanay city,
Kazakhstan**

but your version is correct too